# Redux function call, causes infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a function called changeLoadingStatus and I am using this to fetch data from the backend. When fetching is finished, I am changing the loadingStatus as false and I want to render my data to screen. But it causes an infinite loop. I did not understand why.

Dashboard.js

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.setLoadingStatus(true)
        if (condition1) {
            this.props.onFetchDataTypes()
        }
        if (condition2) {
            this.props.onFetchSts();
        }
        if (condition3) {
            this.props.onFetchSystems();
        }
    }

    render() {
        let dashboardPage = (
            <div>
              <label>xxx</label> 
            </div>
        );

        if (this.props.loadingStatus) {
            dashboardPage = <Spinner />
        }

        return dashboardPage;
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        loadingStatus: state.loadingStatus
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onFetchDataTypes: () => dispatch(actions.fetchDataTypes()),
        onFetchSts: () => dispatch(actions.fetchServiceTypes()),
        onFetchSystems: () => dispatch(actions.fetchSystems()),
        setLoadingStatus: (status) => dispatch(actions.changeLoading(status))
    };
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard));
```

For example in the 'onFetchDataTypes' function, on the axios success response, I set the loadingStatus redux state to false but this causes an infinite loop. If I did not set it to false, there is no infinite loop but of course, the loading spinner is always there

Comment: Is it possible for you to reproduce the issue in a codesandbox, by using fake backend? That would really give some insight on what's going on. Also  how does the error about infinite loop look like? At first look, your code looks fine, so it's diffucult to tell what could be wrong. :)

Comment: Why is there only one loading status to represent 3 fetches? As Rosen commented; there is not much to see here without a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: In fact, I changed my strategy as @HMR said and I have created 3 loaded state for 3 fetches. On the success redux method, I set these loaded states as 'true'. This solved my problem.

Comment: @RosenDimov, there was no specific error but my redux functions were running repeatedly non-stop, again and again :) I did not understand why, but as I said, I solved with an another solution

Comment: It's great you solved it. I can't tell for sure, but even if you're setting 3 times that indicator to ```false``` upon each request, the component you show shoudn't re-render and you also do your requests in ```componentWillMount``` (so once). You can answer the question yourself, it would be interesting to see the exact cause. ;)